# How to pull a value from a website ( Using cUrl in PHP)

Tags: php, dom

I am trying the following script to pull a value from a certain website, however I think this is not a valid DOM Document, I want to know if there is an alternate way?

```
       <?php
      $curl_handle=curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.indiagoldrate.com/gold-rate-in-mumbai-today.htm');
      curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
      curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
      curl_close($curl_handle);
      if (empty($buffer))
      {
          print "Sorry, example.com are a bunch of poopy-heads.<p>";
      }
      else
      {
          print $buffer;
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: there's no api available for the price of gold? I find that unlikely

Comment: There is, the only thing, I have to purchase it!

Comment: well it is cheaper to steal

Comment: I am just doing  a demo project for a client, once I get the green signal that hes interested, I sure will purchase one :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `file_get_contents` try this,

```
$str= htmlentities(file_get_contents('http://www.indiagoldrate.com/gold-rate-in-mumbai-today.htm'));
```

Read [file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: I tried the following, but no success:
<?php 


$data = file_get_contents('http://www.gitanjalijewels.com/category.php?id=39');
$regex = '/GOLD RATES:: (.+?) ,/';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match); 
echo $match[1];
?>

Answer (score 0):

Though the page in your code (http://www.indiagoldrate.com/gold-rate-in-mumbai-today.htm) is not a valid DOM document, you still can parse it with PHP's [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).
For example here we'll get the price of 1g 22k gold in Mumbay city today:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //get rid of the warnings

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($buffer);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$price = $xp->query('//*[@id="right_center"]/table[1]/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tr[1]/td[2]')->item(0)->nodeValue;

libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

var_dump($price);
```